# How to write single update method common for all update actions in codeigniter application?

Tags: php, model, codeigniter-3

I am writing update method to update a table and also I want to use that update method commonly for all update operations. I am passing table name, data to update & where condition but it is not working correctly. Below is my code:

My_controller.php

```
$data = array(
                'column-1' => $this->input->post('form_name1'),
                'column-2' => $this->input->post('form_name2'),
                'column-3' => $this->input->post('form_name3'),
                'column-4' => $this->input->post('form_name4')
            );
$result = $this->my_model->common_update('my_table_name',$data,$user_id ); 
if($result)
{
  $this->session->mark_as_flash('message');
  $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'table updated.');
  redirect(base_url().'index.php/my_page');
}
else{
  $this->session->mark_as_flash('message');
  $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "Table doesn't Updated.");
  $this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

My_model.php

```
public function common_update( $table, $data = array(), $where )
{
    $this->db->where('id', $where);
    $query = $this->db->update($table,$data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 ? true : false ;
}
```

My Database Table structure: table name - "my_table_name"

```
Name      Type  
id        int(10)     AUTO_INCREMENT primary_key
column-1  varchar(20)
column-2  varchar(20)
column-3  varchar(20)
column-4  varchar(20)
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: do you want to pass multiple where conditions?

Comment: No I am passing just only single id i.e., table row id but in future update queries I may pass multiple where conditions but now only single id.

Comment: can you show the db table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Update. $this represent the query..and your calling it before query

```
public function common_update( $table, $data = array(), $where )
{
    $this->db->where('id', $where);
    $query = $this->db->update($table,$data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 ? true : false ;
}
```

with

```
public function common_update( $table, $data = array(), $where )
{

    $query = $this->db->update($table,$data);
             $this->db->where('id', $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 ? true : false ;
}
```

regards  :)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. still no luck, I printed the $this->db->last_query() it is printed all the data correctly but the main 'where' condition is missing. If I update atleast one column then it is working fine but if I don't pass any new data then it is not getting updated.

Comment: @prasadchinthala i think problem is with you send in data parameters..check it properly. check how data is coming in $data parameter

Comment: I updated my question with what data parameters I am passing to the table, please check it once

Comment: @prasadchinthala check keys of data is present in db?? because which keys are you passing it should be a column in table

Comment: yes I am passing the array data with keys as same as table column names. thats why It is getting updated when I update at least one column know which I already said in my above reply.